# What does the red light on the printer mean?

Tags: printer

The printer is a Sharp AR-M160. There are It works fine, but the red light worries me nonetheless.  It is shaped like a repairman - does that mean it needs to be repaired?

[image]

Comment: *check the manual*

Answer (score 4):

It means you have to stop and wait for the green man before you can cross the street.

Just kidding. It means that "Service by an authorized SHARP service technician is required."

Have a look at page 62 of the manual:
http://www.gfive.net/pdf/manuals/AR-M160-Manual.pdf#page=64&zoom=auto,-229,842